# Relative positioning of DIVs

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm doing the HTML & CSS course at codeacademy and I'm a bit confused about positioning.

I've got this html-file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    div {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100px;
        width:  100px;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }

    div p {
       position: relative;
       margin-top: 40px;
       font-size: 12px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><p>Maxime</p></div>
    <div><p>Killian</p></div>
    <div><p></p></div>
</body>
```

So if I leave the code like this I don't get the expected result. Only if I put in a third name in the third div it behaves as I want it too. Take a look at this picture so you know what I mean.
[image]

What is happening here? Why are the nested elements that is the paragraphs changing the behaviour of their parents?

Comment: I don't know why and can't explain so I'm not posting as an answer, but on your CSS for `div p` if you change the position to absolute it seems to render correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the CSS property `vertical-align`. The definition (in terms of a brief summary) of the property as mentioned on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) (You can read more about by clicking the link)is as below :

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an
>   inline or table-cell box.

Below is the screenshot of the section of the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) page mentioned above :

[image]

In the context of this particular example, you can set it as below on the container `div` :

```
div {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

This will make all the contained elemnts align properly. See a working example below :

```css
    div {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        vertical-align: top;    /*Add this property*/
    }
    div p {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 40px;
        font-size: 12px;
        
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Maxime</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Killian</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am trying to frame this in a way so I can understand. 
Since the div elements are parents of the p classes i expected them to get a position first. Via the property `margin-top: 40px;`  the paragraphs should then be offset by 40px from their parent's top.
But really, the div elements don't have a fixed position if I don't assign them one. That is why their children can change their position. Only by adding the property `vertical-align: top;` do the div elements get a fixed position at the top of the canvas. 

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a FLOAT beavour to the Paragraph

```
div p {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 40px;
   font-size: 12px;

   float:left
}
```

[working feedle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrcxbckn/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `position` from `relative` to `absolute` and everything will be lined up.

```
div p {
   position: absolute; /*revised*/
   margin-top: 40px;
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
}
div p {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 </head>
<body>
    <div><p>Maxime</p></div>
    <div><p>Killian</p></div>
    <div><p>Lukas</p></div>
</body>
```